# Difference between ng-controller and controller property

Tags: angularjs

I have been trying to figure this out for a while, but I can't find anywhere that describes it and my testing has not given me any answers.

I have created a custom directive and I want the directive's scope to be a child-scope of the parent scope. I've found two different approaches that solves this.

A:

```
angular.module('myModule').directive('myDirective', function(){
    return{
        scope: true,
        template: '<div>{{var}}</div>',
        controller: function($scope){
            $scope.var = 123;
        }
    };
});
```

B:

```
angular.module('myModule').directive('myDirective', function(){
    return{
        scope: false,
        template: '<div ng-controller="MyController">{{var}}</div>'
    };
});

angular.module('myModule').controller('MyController', function($scope){
    $scope.var = 123;
});
```

What are the differences between these two approaches? Both seem to do what I want, but are there some advantages/disadvantages of using one approach over the other?

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use the latter unless you have a really good reason to do so. If you want to create a reusable controller and use that in your directive, just define the directive as such:

```
angular.module('myModule').directive('myDirective', function(){
    return{
        scope: false,
        controller: 'MyController',
        template: '{{var}}'
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The second approach would allow you to reuse the controller on several elements. The first one is distinct for that directiv and could be shared.

Answer (score 1):

Option B seems able to share the controller. However, from the design perspective, the controllers should not be shared. A controller should contain some particular business logic.

If some model/operations are to be shared, extract to services.